# How do I print a signal on 2min chart, as soon as RSI on 10min crosses the RSI moving average with a already happend ema cross on 2min chart?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have writen a pinescript where I get alternating long/short signals on the 2min chart when I have a 9 and 50 ema crossover (also on the 2min chart), which works as it should. Now I tried to achieve that the signal only gets printed when the RSI on the 10 minute chart crossed the rsi moving average (upwards cross for 2min long signal and downwards cross for 2min short signal).

I tried different approaches and none of them worked.

```
//EMAs
ema9 = ta.ema(close, input.int(9, 'EMA9'))
ema50 = ta.ema(close, input.int(50, 'EMA50'))

//RSI
rsi15 = ta.rsi(close, 15)

//RSI Moving Average
rsi20_moving_avg = ta.rma(close, 20)

ten_min_rsi_15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '10', rsi15)
ten_min_rsi_ma_20 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '10', rsi20_moving_avg)

// we create a variable that "saves" and doesnt calc on each bar 
var cross_trigger = 0
var rsi_trigger = 0

// we save it to a new number when long happens. Long can be 1 
if ta.crossover(ema9, ema50) and cross_trigger <= 0
    cross_trigger := 1
// we save it again when short happens. Short can be -1 
if ta.crossover(ema50, ema9) and cross_trigger >= 0 
    cross_trigger := -1

if (ten_min_rsi_15 > ten_min_rsi_ma_20) and rsi_trigger <= 0
    rsi_trigger := 1

if (ten_min_rsi_15 < ten_min_rsi_ma_20) and rsi_trigger >= 0
    rsi_trigger := -1

// here we check if we have a newly detetected change from another number to our pos number this bar
// Is pos equal to 1 and was it not equal to 1 one bar ago
longsignal  = cross_trigger ==  1 and (cross_trigger !=  1)[1]
shortsignal = cross_trigger == -1 and (cross_trigger != -1)[1]

//Plot
// we change our plot shape to coincide with the change detection 
plotshape(longsignal,  style=shape.triangleup, color=#26a69a, text="LONG", textcolor=#ffffff, location=location.bottom, size=size.small)
plotshape(shortsignal, style=shape.triangledown, color=#ef5350, text="SHORT", textcolor=#ffffff, location=location.top, size=size.small)

// Alerts
alertcondition(longsignal, title='CALL', message='CALL')
alertcondition(shortsignal, title='PUT', message='PUT')
```

As I said, the cross trigger works for alternating long short signals. I also prepared the rsi trigger but I dont know how to add it to the longsignal/shortsignal.

Btw. I used the logic of this post: [How do I stop multiple BUY/SELL signals from printing in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426669/how-do-i-stop-multiple-buy-sell-signals-from-printing-in-a-row)

Answer (score 0):

On the 2min chart, you just need to check if `ema9 > ema50`. If this is the case, You already know that the cross took place there.

Then on the higher timeframe, just look for the `crossover` event.

```
htf_crossover = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '10', ta.crossover(rsi15, rsi20_moving_avg))
```

Comment: Well thats fine. My problem is, that I wont get a signal triggered if its not both at the same time. Sometimes the ema cross comes in on the 2min but the rsi cross on 10min comes later. In addition I dont get how I add the rsi crossover to the longsignal/shortsignal.